# Matlab: showing anomalies in a plot

Tags: matlab, plot, data-visualization

How can make I tiny sticks like those shown in red surroundings in the plot below? I used a binary vector of anomalies (1 if anomaly 0 if not) and used plot function, but rather I' d like to see spikes like in the figure.

These sticks correspond to anomaly indicators in the data such as discontinuities (as can be seen in the plot). I'd also like if you could propose good alternative visualizations.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Matlab allows [drawing rectangles](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html) on the plot.